Having problems with pip install: packaging.specifiers.InvalidSpecifier: Invalid specifier: '>="3.8"'
I'm totally new to coding in general. I was trying to run "pip install vision" command on my CMD which runs as administrator. I have following messages appearing for me:
 C:\Windows\system32>pip install vision
Collecting vision
  Using cached vision-1.0.0.tar.gz (1.6 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [53 lines of output]
      C:\Users\kaank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-91jsn09u\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:296: _DeprecatedConfig: Deprecated config in `setup.cfg`
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              The namespace_packages parameter is deprecated, consider using implicit namespaces instead (PEP 420).

              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        parsed = self.parsers.get(option_name, lambda x: x)(value)
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\kaank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\kaank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\kaank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\kaank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-91jsn09u\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 332, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\kaank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-91jsn09u\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 302, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\kaank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-91jsn09u\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 502, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\kaank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-91jsn09u\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 318, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\kaank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-91jsn09u\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 111, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\kaank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-91jsn09u\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 158, in setup
          dist.parse_config_files()
        File "C:\Users\kaank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-91jsn09u\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 602, in parse_config_files
          setupcfg.parse_configuration(
        File "C:\Users\kaank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-91jsn09u\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py", line 178, in parse_configuration
          options.parse()
        File "C:\Users\kaank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-91jsn09u\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py", line 503, in parse
          section_parser_method(section_options)
        File "C:\Users\kaank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-91jsn09u\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py", line 478, in parse_section
          self[name] = value
          ~~~~^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\kaank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-91jsn09u\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py", line 296, in __setitem__
          parsed = self.parsers.get(option_name, lambda x: x)(value)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\kaank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-91jsn09u\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\specifiers.py", line 718, in __init__
          self._specs = frozenset(map(Specifier, split_specifiers))
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\kaank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-91jsn09u\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\specifiers.py", line 237, in __init__
          raise InvalidSpecifier(f"Invalid specifier: '{spec}'")
      packaging.specifiers.InvalidSpecifier: Invalid specifier: '>="3.8"'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I am keen to understand what am I missing to install this package properly.
I installed Python 3.12.5. I was trying to run a OpenCV game bot., I installed some packages successfully but when it comes to install https://pypi.org/project/vision/#files I am having this problem.
I tried to research my problem but nothing came out of it so far.

that "vision" package is abandoned (last activity 4 years ago), its "homepage" link is broken. why do you even try to install that?

See my full answer below. -- Are you 100% sure it is the exact name vision that you are meant to install? Where from did you get the info that you should install vision?

As far as I can tell this vision package on PyPI is not meant to be installed. Here is its description:

This package is present in the Public PyPi repositories to prevent package conflicts between Open Source Python packages and Verizon Media internal packages.

So we understand that its presence on PyPI is meant to prevent from "dependency confusion attack". In this case, I assume that the people at Yahoo/Verizon Media (the plausible owners) have a vision Python package in their private internal repository. In order to prevent their employees to install a potentially malicious vision package from the public PyPI by mistake instead of installing from their private internal repository, they took the preventive step of taking ownership of the vision name on the public PyPI. This way no one else can upload a malicious package under the vision name.
If you look at the content of the vision package on PyPI, you will see that there is no meaningful code in there. Even if the packaging did not have issues and it were installable, no import package or module would get installed.
